# CORS error when Firebase Cloud function deployed using --no-allow-unauthenticated

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-functions

Calling next 2gen Cloud Function implemented in Go, I'm getting CORS error when it's deployed using the `--no-allow-unauthenticated` parameter.

When calling with auth disabled (`--allow-unauthenticated`), I can see the Authorization cookie with the Bearer token.

This is the Go Function implementation:

```golang
func FntTestingWithAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    // Set Cors in OPTIONS call
    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
        //w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
        fmt.Println("OPTIONS EXECUTED so return back!!!!!\n")
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("[%s] has been EXECUTED!!!!!\n", r.Method)
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it from the frontend:

```js
  const testingFn = httpsCallable(functions(), "testing");

  testingFn(requestParams).then((result) => {
    alert(result.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
```

I have tested similar function using (in fact, used it for a while) implemented in typescript and it's working fine. In this case, I don't need to configure CORS at all.

```js
functions
  .runWith({

  })
  .https
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {
    return {
      "response": "working",
    };
  });
```

What could be the reason?

Testing and searching for hours (a lot of hours) and no lucky. So I'm missing something for sure.

Comment: The Firebase SDKs handle CORS for you automatically, as documented by the [protocol spec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  If you're not use a Firebase SDK on either end, you need to implement that spec fully yourself so the other end gets what it expects. One can only guess that your go implementation isn't correct somehow.

Comment: I'll also point out that the flags used for GCP authentication are unrelated to CORS.  Disabled auth is required for public HTTP endpoints for clients that aren't using IAM credentials to invoke the function. Functions deployed by the Firebase CLI have auth disabled by default because the expectation is that they're being used for public endpoints to be invoked by a web or mobile app.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm using [Firebase admin SDKs for go](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4) and [Cloud Functions for go](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime). Do you mean that this is only working if using the [Javascript Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd) which contains the onCall helper?

Comment: What you linked is not the Admin SDK.  It's the Functions SDK (they are different things).  And yes, it is the only provided implementation of callable functions for backend use.  It's open source and you can learn from it to implement your own if you want.

Comment: I got your point.